# How to concatenate a string and tez in Liquidity?

Tags: liquidity

How can I concatenate a string and a tez value in Liquidity?

```
let a = 1.00tz;
let b = "Amount is: "; // <- how to get a in there?
```

A more real world example;

I have an `addCost` in my storage (admins can change it to track $ price) and I would like to reflect the cost in fail messages:

```
if (amount < storage.addCost) {
  Current.failwith("Not enough money, at least <addCost> to add")
};
```

How can I get the `addCost` value in there...?

Comment: There is no nice way to do this. Maybe the real question ought to be about _why_ you want to do this... I can't think of a good reason.

Comment: @Tom I added a more real world example for why I want to do this. Surely it's not impossible...? I could make the addCost a string, but then I would need to convert it to a tez value when comparing to current.amount() ‍♂️

Comment: Figured out I can do `Current.failwith(("Not enough money", storage.addCost))` to at least communicate the amount in the fail message. However, still think there has to be a way to do this...?

Comment: Do you really want to ask "how to format tez as string", or something more like "how to provide user-friendly error data"? The latter question is interesting and seems to be the real question here. If you want to ask the latter, I suggest explaining your goals more explicitly, and your thoughts about various approaches. If you really want to ask the former, I can provide a boring answer. :)

Comment: For now, and for other people who might find this later, I want to ask the former and collect a boring answer  Feel free to add some notes regarding the latter to your answer if you feel like it 

Comment: I need to do the same thing with a contract that allows end users to mint an NFT directly from the contract. If you want to name them consecutively such as "My Token #1" ... then you need to be able to increment a counter and then combine it with the token name string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no Michelson ops for formatting values as strings.

Unless a protocol change adds such operations, it seems that the best way to convert mutez (or int, nat) to string will be to write the algorithm manually:

- First, we can convert mutez to nat by dividing by 1 mutez, using EDIV.
- Now we can do a loop, iteratively dividing the nat value by 10, again using EDIV. The remainders give us each successive digit of the decimal representation. We must map each digit 0-9 to the corresponding string "0"-"9", perhaps using a literal `map nat string`. Of course, once we get to zero, we are done.
- If we want to format mutez as a tez string, we need to add a decimal place and might drop trailing zeros after the decimal.
- To concatenate the string bits together we will use CONCAT. There are two forms of CONCAT. I think it is generally more gas-efficient to build up a `list string` and CONCAT it all at once, rather than doing a bunch of binary string/string CONCATs.

It seems like this is going to require a decent chunk of code. This will cost you some origination burn. You will probably consume gas for this code on *every* transaction to your contract, whether the code is executed or not.

You can mitigate this gas cost by putting the conversion code once in a lambda. You will still pay the cost once per transaction.

You could mitigate the gas cost even more by doing some big_map gymnastics, loading the lambda from the big_map only when it is needed.

Perhaps, in your case, the gas costs are not a concern. I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for a fantastic and detailed answer  Although disappointing it is this hard to do such a "common" operation. Thanks 